# How can I find if there is comparison between two objects in a sentence or not?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Good day.
First I would like to apologies for not being very specific in the title, please if anyone knows the correct term for what I need, do let me know.
Here is my question. There is a person X and a person Y and I'm doing sentiment analysis on each person. Here are the two case that are baffling me (have in mind that the cases here are simplified) .

- Case 1: "X is outperforming Y"
- Case 2: "X's performance is outstanding while Y's performance is poor"

When doing sentiment analysis in Case 2 you can just split the sentence in two and do the analysis separately for the part for X and the part for Y while this would not work for Case 1. There is a relationship between X and Y in #1 which means that in sentences in that type if X is good than Y is bad. 
So here is my question: Is there any way to recognize sentence structures like in case 2. I was thinking of POS tagging but since I'm not a native speaker (and my grammar is bad) it's a bit hard for me to see how this would work.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

POS tagging is not enough. You'll want to use a dependency parser (e.g. [MaltParser](http://www.maltparser.org/)) to find out the grammatical structure of the sentence.

How you would do sentiment analysis on the result, I leave to you. I'm not aware of any algorithm or model that handles this kind of sentence, but I imagine you can find some by googling for "sentiment analysis" (or any of its near-synonyms) + "dependency parsing", or maybe something like "relative sentiment/opinion/polarity".